# ¿como consumir un web api , desde MVC.asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Tengo mi **Web API** en **ASP.NET** , necesito hacer un simple abml consumiendo los servicios desde el controlador de **MVC**. Me podrían ayudar?
El **WEB API** que tengo es el que te genera el *scaffolding*

Comment: No tengo mucho trabajando con MVC pero tienes tu controller de Web API, no es cierto que si le das en view > add ya te consume el Web API desde ASP .Net Razor?

Comment: sisi, pero la idea es consumir el web api desde una aplicación cliente de mvc, o sea tengo 2 proyectos ,el web api y el mvc, el mvc es el proyecto que consume la api.

Comment: Los dos proyectos están dentro de la misma solución?

Comment: si, en la misma solucion.

Comment: A mí me pasó lo mismo, pero mi PM me dijo que la consumiera vía AJAX, usé JQuery, pero esperamos pasarnos a AngularJS para la siguiente versión

Comment: Ok, si los dos proyectos estan en la misma solución, y quieres consumir la lógica que está en el api del proyecto "A" desde un controlador que está en el proyecto "B", realmente no tienes porqué consumir esta lógica por Rest. Lo que yo haría es tener un tercer proyecto donde comparto esa lógica entre los dos proyectos y listo. Hacerlo por Rest para consumirlo desde un controller es añadir un poco más de complejidad que no se requiere.

Comment: encontre una pagina con un ejemplo completo  se las dejo: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1192/aspnet-web-api-async-calls-mvc-wpf  gracias chicos por su ayuda,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para eso debes usar la clase `HttpClient`

Por ejemplo para hacer un `GET`

> Nota: Ejemplo adaptado de: [Calling a Web API From a .NET Client in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

```
public Task<Product> GetProduct(int id)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://url-base-del-api");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        // Agrega el header Accept: application/json para recibir la data como json  
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        // Hace la llamada a http://url-base-del-api/api/products/<id>
        var response = await client.GetAsync("api/products/" + id);

        // Si el servicio responde correctamente
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // Lee el response y lo deserializa como un Product
            return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
        }
        // Sino devuelve null
        return Task.FromResult<Product>(null);
    }
}
```