# como generar token realizando la petición desde un controlador

Tags: vb.net

Estoy utilizando web api 2 en Visual Basic, asi mismo utilizo autenticación basada en token, genero el token con la ayuda del OAuthProvider que viene incluida al momento de generar un proyecto WEB API desde visual studio, lo que necesito es que a partir de una función el alguno de mis controladores pueda acceder y generar el token con la ayuda del HttpClient pero aún no sé como implementarlo, el código que tengo el el siguiente:

En el controlador llamado TOPICOS:

```
Public Function GetValues() As List(Of TOPICOS)
    Using client = New HttpClient()

        client.BaseAddress = New Uri("http://localhost:7910/")

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear()
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(New MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"))

  Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = client.GetAsync("api/Libros/2").Result

        Dim formContent = New FormUrlEncodedContent(New Object() {
                                                New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("grant_type", "password"),
                                                New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("UserName", "usu"),
                                                New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("Password", "pass")
                                            })

    End Using

End Function
```

De hecho tengo una linea de código que consulta otra api llamada Libros y a ella puedo acceder, pero mi tarea principal es acceder y general el token, he encontrado los siguientes ejemplos pero aun no sé como aplicarlos (estos ejemplos estánn en C#)

[¿Como consumir Web API desde C# pasando un Json como parámetro?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3783/como-consumir-web-api-desde-c-pasando-un-json-como-par%C3%A1metro)

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/martinkearn/2015/03/25/securing-and-securely-calling-web-api-and-authorize/

[¿como consumir un web api , desde MVC.asp.net?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/20695/como-consumir-un-web-api-desde-mvc-asp-net)

Si alguien pudiera ayudar...

Comment: Bueno, he podido solucionarlo, basicamente lo que hacia incorrectamente era formar la estructura o los datos del contenido de la petición, he hecho lo siguiente y me ha funcionado:

`Dim form = New Dictionary(Of String, String)() From { _
                {"grant_type", "password"}, _
                {"username", "gchab"}, _
                {"password", "ss"}, _
                {"idProyecto", "1"} _
                }`

y en base a la estructura anterior puedo realizar la petición:

Comment: `Dim tokenResponse = client.PostAsync("Token", New FormUrlEncodedContent(form)).Result`

para ello igual tuve que crear una clase para acceder a cada uno de las propiedades del token: 

`Public Class Token Public Property access_token As String Public Property token_type As String Public Property expires_in As Integer Public Property refresh_token As String Public Property errorr As String End Class`